# Should I keep images at original size for a better classification?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, data-science

I'm building an image classification model with keras.
I have images of several dimensions, the smaller one being 400x400.

Let's suppose that every image is a square, so proportions should be safe: is it bad to scale them to, say, 64x64 to make processing faster?
Or, in order to achieve best quality, is it better to keep them as close as possible to their original size?

I would say that scale them is good as it helps avoiding overfitting, but I'd like to hear your opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct on scaling the image helps avoiding overfitting. However the answer depends on your objective. Do you require faster processing or higher quality images? Images as small as 400x400 need high quality to render visibly.